# Text processing app to delete duplicate lines in text file

Tags: windows, plain-text, text-processing

I have a large text file with over 20,000 lines.  The order of the lines is important.  I want to remove all duplicate non-blank lines in the file, without disturbing the order.  What [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) software can accomplish this task?

If possible, I would like to manually confirm/deny the deletion of each duplicate line.

For this task:

- I prefer [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) software.  This is not a requirement, but the software must cost no more than a milkshake.
- I prefer [portable](/questions/tagged/portable) software (no installer), but this is not a requirement.

Comment: Might be worth a look [Removing duplicate rows in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad)

Comment: @Huey Thanks Huey.  Most of the answers required changing the order of the lines.  The answers that did not specify this requirement, unfortunately, did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [Remove Duplicate Lines](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/remove-duplicate-lines/). It's an online app that will delete duplicate text lines.

However, it will not allow you to manually confirm/deny the deletion of each duplicate line.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, my inclination for this kind of (relatively simple) text processing is to write a quick and dirty script. So here is a quick and dirty Powershell script you could modify to your needs. For 20 000 line files I think that the `get-content` command should be okay but if your files are too big then you may need other optimizations (hashing lines as dictionary keys, using the .NET `System.IO.StreamReader` class...). There are other ways to improve things as well.

```
# Create a file consisting of an original file with duplicate lines 
# removed, preserving line order.
# Run this at your own risk!

# Paul "Worthless" Nijjar, 2016-03-29

param(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $InFile,

   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $OutFile,

   [parameter()][switch] $ConfirmRemovals
)

if ($InFile -eq $OutFile) { 
    write-error("Input and Output files should be different: $OutFile")
}

# Store all unique lines in a dictionary!
$linemap = @{}
$lineNumber = 0

# I hope you didn't need OutFile!
echo $null > $OutFile

foreach ($currLine in (Get-Content $InFile)) {
    $lineNumber++
    $outline =  "{0}:`"{1}`"" -f $lineNumber, $currLine
    write-debug $outline
    if ($currLine.trim() -eq "" ) { 
        # Line is blank. Preserve it. 
        $currLine >> $OutFile
    } elseif (! $linemap.ContainsKey($currLine)) { 
        # Not a duplicate. Record in map and write to file.
        $linemap.Set_Item($currLine, $lineNumber)
        $currLine >> $OutFile
    } else { 
        $outline = "Line {0} `"{1}`" is a duplicate of line {2}" -f $lineNumber, $currLine, $linemap.Get_Item($currLine)
        write-host $outline

        if ($ConfirmRemovals) { 
            $omitIt = read-host -prompt "Omit it? (y/n)"
            if ($omitIt -ne "y") { 
                write-host "Not deleting."
                $currLine >> $OutFile
            } else { 
                write-host "Omitting by confirmation."

            } # end if omitIt check
        } else { 
            write-host "Omitting."
        } # End if confirm removals

    } # end if linemap contains key

} # end get-content
```

I saved the file as `Select-NonDuplicates.ps1` .

Here is a sample input file (`in.txt`):

```
cat
bat
Cat
cat
The above two WILL be duplicates!
Powershell is case insensitive for dictionary strings.
frogg
frog
Rabbit
 Rabbit
The above will not be a duplicate.
Be careful of leading spaces. trim() can help here.
 Rabbit

Blank lines will be preserved.


Monkey
Monkey  
The above will not be a duplicate.
Be careful of trailing spaces, too.
frog
frog
Rabbit
Cat
Mountain goat
```

and here the corresponding output file (`out.txt`):

```
cat
bat
The above two WILL be duplicates!
Powershell is case insensitive for dictionary strings.
frogg
frog
Rabbit
 Rabbit
The above will not be a duplicate.
Be careful of leading spaces. trim() can help here.

Blank lines will be preserved.


Monkey
Monkey  
Be careful of trailing spaces, too.
Mountain goat
```

I invoke this by opening a command prompt and starting powershell as:

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned
```

and then at the prompt typing

```
& Select-NonDuplicates.ps1 -InFile in.txt -Outfile out.txt
```

To confirm removals, type:

```
& Select-NonDuplicates.ps1 -InFile in.txt -Outfile out.txt -ConfirmRemovals
```

(The usual disclaimers apply: I am a mediocre programmer and there are probably bugs, the code is not well tested and might ruin everything, I apologise if this level of detail comes across as patronizing, Windows costs more than a milkshake.)

Comment: Thanks Paul!  Nothing patronizing at all!  Since powershell is free with Windows, and I've already paid for it, the overall financial cost is zero.  I'll take a look at what you've created as soon as I can.  It might be perfect!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

[AkelPad](http://akelpad.sourceforge.net) and [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) can do that. Both handle 20,000 lines easily.

AkelPad: Options → Plug-ins... → Format::LineRemoveDuplicates → Call

It won't be interactive, but you can see the lines to be removed by using Format::LineGetDuplicates

<sup>The installer comes with plug-ins, but if you are going to use the portable version, make sure to install **Format** plug-in.</sup>

Geany:
Tools → Plugin Manager → enable Line Operations → Close
Tools → Line Operations → Remove Duplicate Lines, Ordered

Comment: Thank you very much! I gave AkelPad a try, and it was *very* fast.  Unfortunately, it also wants to remove about 500 blank lines interspersed throughout the file.  Is it possible to ignore the blank lines in AkelPad?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, not that I know of. I totally missed that requirement, sorry. It should be doable via Scripts plug-in, you may want to ask on the [forum](http://akelpad.sourceforge.net/forum/).

Comment: No problem at all.  Thank you for the recommendations!